# Set global environment variables in VS Code with remote-ssh

Tags: visual-studio-code, remote-server

I have the case that I need to use VS Code installed on Windows 10 and run it with the extension [Remote - SSH](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh) on a RHEL 7.x. 
The default RHEL 7.x runs with git 1.8.x. I have installed a newer git version but this is not in the default $PATH environment.

I have found this instructions https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl#_advanced-environment-setup-script which describe how to set the environment variables specifically for VS Code when usind WSL.

> If you want to run additional commands or modify the environment this can be done in a setup script ~/.vscode-server/server-env-setup

This does seem to work only if you use WSL. Why does this not work with the [Remote - SSH extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh)?

My special case is that I only want and need the git>=2 while usind VS Code. When I am connected regularly via ssh I would like and need the OS default tools and settings.
This gives me the special request that I don't want to edit the `~/.bashrc`, `~/.cshrc` or any other user environment files.
I would like to be able to edit the environment for VS Code only. Some kind, maybe like:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
export PATH=/opt/rh/rh-git29/root/usr/bin\:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/rh/httpd24/root/usr/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
...
```

```csh
#!/bin/csh
setenv PATH /opt/rh/rh-git29/root/usr/bin\:$PATH
setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /opt/rh/httpd24/root/usr/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
...
```

Is there anything I have not found yet where I can make my requests to work or would this be some kind of request to the VS Code Team?

Regards.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think I found the solution in [this issue comment](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/1671#issuecomment-542798353) and the follow-up response:

- When vscode-server initially starts, it uses a login shell, sourcing `.profile` in your home directory.
- However, any following interactive shells started through VS Code are non-login shells and thus only source `.bashrc`
- A complication in fiddling with this is that vscode-server apparently caches the environment during its lifetimes, so changes to these dotfiles don't become visible until the server is restarted.

Comment: Note to self: the relevant command is called "Remote-SSH: Kill VS Code Server on Host". But it didn't work properly for me, so I went for good old server-side `killall node`.

Comment: After many VSC updates I started to use the `"git.path": "<git_location>"` in the settings.json it is working fine with ssh repositories.

Comment: In my case, I must create a ` ~/.bash_profile` : `source ~/.zshrc` then `killall node`. Work well, add things to settings not work for me.

Comment: point 2 saved me lots continuing pain, thank you

Comment: This answer helped me solve a huge headache with a ghost env var that I deleted out of my zshrc but wouldn't go away no matter what I did in the vscode terminal. Killing the vscode server on the host fixed it. Another thing I've noticed is that (at least using python) it will also automatically set anything in a .env file as environment variables in your terminal session. So if you're using a .env lib that doesn't override shell env vars, you're going to be very confused (like me) why changing your .env doesn't work. I don't understand why this is default behaviour without any kind of notice..

Answer (score 0):

I have a better solution to minimize the proxy scope

```
export http_proxy=<proxy here>
export no_proxy=<no proxy here>
while IFS= read -r _file; do
    if ! grep -s -q "export http_proxy=" "${_file}"; then
        sed -i -e "/^ROOT/i export http_proxy=${http_proxy}" -e "/^ROOT/i export https_proxy=${http_proxy}" -e "/^ROOT/i export no_proxy=${no_proxy}" "${_file}"
    fi
done < <(find ~/.vscode-server/bin -type f -name "server.sh")
```